# Nulla referencia al invocar un recycler view

Tags: android, firebase

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference

Tengo un error cuando quiero recargar un fragment que contiene un recycler view, el en un inicio funciona bien, pero cuando quiero forzarlo a actualizar, tocando en el boton del bottomNavigationBar, del fragment alojado, dice que tiene una excepción en el adapter que seteo en un metodo para filtro de busqueda.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        listaIncendios = new ArrayList<>();
        search = (androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView) root.findViewById(R.id.action_search);
        cargarRecyclerView();
        FloatingActionButton  btn = root.findViewById(R.id.floatingButton);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Navigation.findNavController(root).navigate(R.id.action_navigation_home_to_navigation_pantalla2);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
```

Este es el metodo que carga el recycler sin filtro

```
  public void cargarRecyclerView(){
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.collection("incendios").orderBy("severidad", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).orderBy("estado", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).orderBy("fecha", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        //Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                        ModelIncendios incendio = document.toObject(ModelIncendios.class);
                        transformarDeVueltaString(incendio);
                        listaIncendios.add(new HomeModel(incendio));

                    }
                    /*Log.d(TAG, "tamano  "+listaIncendios.size());*/
                    contenedor = root.findViewById(R.id.container);
                    contenedor.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    contenedor.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    LinearLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(root.getContext());
                    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                    contenedor.setAdapter(new HomeAdapter(listaIncendios));
                    contenedor.setLayoutManager(layout);
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Donde creo el search view para filtrar

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchitem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        menuSearch = (SearchView) searchitem.getActionView();
        if (menuSearch != null){
            menuSearch.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    buscar(newText);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

El metodo de busqueda que estoy seguro que es aquí donde me da el null point

```
private  void buscar(String str){
        ArrayList<HomeModel> myList =  new ArrayList<>();
        for (HomeModel object: listaIncendios){
            if (object.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase()) || object.getState().toLowerCase()
                .contains(str.toLowerCase()) || object.getDate().toString().toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())
                    || object.getSeverity().toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())

            ){
                myList.add(object);
            }
        }
        
        contenedor.setAdapter(new HomeAdapter(myList));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si te fijas obtienes el error al llamar setAdapter() en una instancia con valor null que en este caso es `contenedor`, la referencia de la vista se obtiene a partir del layout cargado en la vista `root`

```
public void cargarRecyclerView(){
   ...
   contenedor = root.findViewById(R.id.container);
   ...
   ...
   contenedor.setAdapter(new HomeAdapter(listaIncendios));
   ...
}
```

debes asegurar que el layout `fragment_home.xml` que infla y define en la variable `root`:

```
 root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
```

contenga en verdad la vista con id `container`